# Protractor: define Allure reporter resultsDir to be located elsewhere

Tags: directory, protractor, report, allure

I'm using Protractor and jasmine-allure-reporter. I'm running protractor from bash script and the problem is with resultsDir, because I want results to generate in a specific folder. Currently they generate in **~/e2e/project_name/conf/allure-results/** folder. What I need is to have them generated in `~/e2e/reports/project_name/allure_results/`. Simply entering full path `resultsDir: '/home/e2e/reports/project_name/allure-results'` in resultsDir parameter changes nothing. How can I solve this?

Current setup in conf.js file:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
    allureReport: {
        resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }
}));
```

Desired setup in conf.js file:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
    allureReport: {
        resultsDir: '~/e2e/reports/project_name/allure_results/allure-results'
    }
}));
```

Comment: It should work Dear.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Whatever I write in resultsDir parameter, it still generates results in `~/e2e/project_name/conf/allure-results/`. For example if I set it to `~/e2e/does_not_exist_folder_name/conf/allure-results/` it still generates them in `~/e2e/project_name/conf/allure-results/`.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for you:

There is one file named `Jasmine2AllureReporter.js` under `\node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter\src\jasmine2AllureReporter.js`.

Open the file:

Change the following and try:

As i have taken example of `D:\\K\\allure-results`

Change the same under `pluginConfig.resultsDir` and `var outDir`, It will work.

```
function Jasmine2AllureReporter(userDefinedConfig, allureReporter) {
var Status = {PASSED: 'passed', FAILED: 'failed', BROKEN: 'broken', PENDING: 'pending'};
this.allure = allureReporter || allure;
this.configure = function(userDefinedConfig) {
var pluginConfig = {};
userDefinedConfig = userDefinedConfig || {};
pluginConfig.resultsDir = 'D:\\K\\allure-results';
//pluginConfig.resultsDir = userDefinedConfig.resultsDir || 'allure-results';
pluginConfig.basePath = userDefinedConfig.basePath || '.';
// var outDir = path.resolve(pluginConfig.basePath, pluginConfig.resultsDir);
var outDir = 'D:\\K\\allure-results';
this.allure.setOptions({targetDir: outDir});
};
```

Comment: This could be useful, but in my case it isn't. Namely, let say we have **project_name_1** and **project_name_2**. So I would have folder named **reports/project_name_1** and **reports/project_name_2**, each containing own results. In the example you have sent this is not possible. So my main goal is to have reports separated by projects. For example in **conf.js** for project 1, `resultsDir: '~/.../results/project_name_1'` folder and in **conf.js** for project 2, `resultsDir: '~/...results/project_name_2'` folder.

Comment: Currently 10. Do you have any other suggestion perhaps?

Comment: Probably you can create 10-jasmine-allure-reporter like jasmine-allure-reporter-1 and so on. And then change it in conf as well `var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter-1');` so that you will have 10 individual `jasmine2AllureReporter.js`  files

Comment: There is one file `node_modules\jasmine-allure-reporter\test\unit\allureReporter.spec.js`
In that `var Reporter = require('../../src/Jasmine2AllureReporter.js').Jasmine2AllureReporter;`

Probably you can create 10 `Jasmine2AllureReporter.js`  and personalize them

Give it a try.

Comment: Good point, but I'll do it another way. The problem with your suggestion is that in the end we can end up with N number of allure reporters, which are all the same, except that resultsDir is different for each.Therefore I'll run each bash script in each project folder, which is not an elegant solution, but currently works.

Comment: Please have a look at this file `allureReporte‌​r.spec.js`